Globally set custom spring validation messages
Is there a way to set error messages for particular constraints/validators globally? I.e. i want all @NotNull constraint to have a validation message (like "Need a value here", or whatever) without writing @NotNull(message=...) on every occurence.
Is is possible to globally define default messages?
I tried to put something like the following in my messages.properties file. But it did not work.
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=...

As pointed out in the first answer, i forgot to mention my validator setup in the spring configuration.
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        return createMessageSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        final LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }


Which Spring Boot version are you using?

2.7.0, i forgot to mention that

Why are you creating a MessageSource spring boot already provides that, just add it as an argument to your validator method and it will be automatically injected (else you are overriding the auto-config behavior of Spring Boot). You also shouldn't need the validator configuration in the first place (nor the MessageSource) as that is setup already by Spring Boot.

I think it was an issue with the default encoding not working for us. It is a multi user project i did not add that part. Would need investigation to check up on that.

You can set the encoding through properties, so that still shouldn't be needed. Anyway I also believe that when doing this Spring will lookup different messages instead of the default ones. Try adding a notnull=<yourmessage here> to the messages.properties. Else you can enable debug logging and see for which elements the MessageSource is being consulted.

Okay, just with a quick check indeed i seem to be able to remove that part from my configuration without making a difference. However neither notnull=... nor javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=... from my messages gets picked up, no matter if there is a custom bean configuration or not.

As stated enable debug logging to see which messages (or validation error codes) are actually being checked. I believe they are different from the default error codes, which will then fallback to the default ones from the Validation framework.

Thank you for trying to help. I am not able to get it to print anything though.

Did you enable TRACE logging? How did you enable it and where?

Yes, i had logging.level.org.springframework.context=TRACE, did log a lot. But not from the message source, decompiled code seems to second that nothing is going to be logged. Its hard to tell for sure, but still seems another MessageSource is used as a breakpoint did not stop for the validation message but for all other strings. Or am i in the wrong place? Which class is supposed to emit that info?

Enable debug/trace logging through spring boot by adding debug=true or trace=true. You would need it for the whole org.springframework namespace not just context, as the validation errors are from the validation part or web part incase of binding errors.

As mentioned in the comments and listed in the spring-boot changelog the below code is no longer needed in spring since version 2.6.0

I believe you need to overwrite the default Validator for it to use your custom messages this can be done like this
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public WebConfig(MessageSource messageSource)
    {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() 
    {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
    }
}


Thank you, i forgot to mention that is already set up. I edited the question.

This is done by Spring Boot already so you don't need to set anything up. In fact spring boot sets up the MessageInterpolator, you can set either one but it shouldn't be needed.

Hmmm... maybe in a different version? I think, if i remember correctly, i needed that part for custom validations with custom error messages to work.

This has been added since Spring Boot 2.6.

My answer is a snippet from a project that was initially build on Spring 2.3 or 2.4, so it could indeed be possible that they added this in 2.6. I'll check the changelog and update the answer accordingly

Could be the same for this project. Thanks for pointing this out.
